# Do re-indexing of database runs automatically with CRM app?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2016, maintenance-plan

It's my first time using CRM as an app. I have been using SQL Server for quite a while now. Our company is experiencing issues with emails, thus having warnings in event viewer

> Query execution time of 17.3 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds.'

for almost all select statements.

My main concern here is I am in doubt that the CRM job tool for reindexing is not running properly. Also, I have checked the reindex maintenance plan in the SQL Server, no configurations were made for reindex.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dynamics 2016 On Premises you are free to create and maintain your own indexes. What is needed really depends on how your company is using the system. Sometimes recalculating statistics does the trick (as far as I remember this is part of the built-in maintenance jobs), sometimes you may even want to partition the database.

E-mail storage in MS Dynamics can quickly grow out of hand, because attachments (e.g. these colorful company footers) use to take up a lot of valuable database space. Decide what e-mail really needs to be tracked, if attachments and images can be stripped from them or if they can be stored in a separate file group. (To mention a few options.)

Poor SQL Server management is actually often the ground reason for performance issues on MS Dynamics. Your skills will be of much value!